# How to track button selection after long press?

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to imitate the long press of the keyboard suggesting a letter for **UIButton** control. What I am trying to do is long press on **UIButton**, after keep pressing on the button 3 new buttons shows and select one of these 3 new buttons. just like the Keyboard letter suggestion. [image]

How can I do this? any idea? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have `UIControl` just for that [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer) 
And you can set the time of the press by `minimumPressDuration` property

If you want this behavior on `UIButton` you have to add this gesture recognizer to the button and handle the first calling (single tap).

Comment: I already added the UILongPressGestureRecogniser to the first button, but the problem is when i move my finger to the second button (first button is still long pressed), I am not getting that the second button is touched

Answer (score 1):

You have a complete set of events on UIControl (UIButton is its subclass) to handle all the touch events that you need:

```
enum {
   UIControlEventTouchDown           = 1 <<  0,
   UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat     = 1 <<  1,
   UIControlEventTouchDragInside     = 1 <<  2,
   UIControlEventTouchDragOutside    = 1 <<  3,
   UIControlEventTouchDragEnter      = 1 <<  4,
   UIControlEventTouchDragExit       = 1 <<  5,
   UIControlEventTouchUpInside       = 1 <<  6,
   UIControlEventTouchUpOutside      = 1 <<  7,
   UIControlEventTouchCancel         = 1 <<  8,

   UIControlEventValueChanged        = 1 << 12,

   UIControlEventEditingDidBegin     = 1 << 16,
   UIControlEventEditingChanged      = 1 << 17,
   UIControlEventEditingDidEnd       = 1 << 18,
   UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,

   UIControlEventAllTouchEvents      = 0x00000FFF,
   UIControlEventAllEditingEvents    = 0x000F0000,
   UIControlEventApplicationReserved = 0x0F000000,
   UIControlEventSystemReserved      = 0xF0000000,
   UIControlEventAllEvents           = 0xFFFFFFFF
};
```

- `UIControlEventTouchDown` will fire when you touch the button
- `UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat` will fire if you continue holding the button (notice that this event will fire many times, so you should handle only the first one) - here you should display the popover
- `UIControlEventTouchDragExit` will fire when you drag the finger out from the button - here you should hide the popover
- `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter` will fire when you drag the finger into the button - here you should display the popover
- `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`, `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` and `UIControlEventTouchCancel` will fire when you lift the finger from the button - here you should hide the popover
- etc.

**UPDATE**
You will have some logic to implement to handle dragging the finger inside the popover (because then you will drag out from the button) though.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old, but as I had the same problem I will present my solution for it.

I have my keyboard laid out and created by class Keyboard, derived from UIView
Each of the letter buttons is of class LetterButton, derived from UIButton.
Keyboard implements a protocol which handles KeyPressed events from the buttons.

For each button of the main keyboard a UILongPressGestureRecognizer is applied:

```
let longTouchRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onButtonLongPressed))
longTouchRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
button.addGestureRecognizer(longTouchRecognizer)
button.delegate = self
```

with

```
@objc func onButtonLongPressed (_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    if (sender.state == .began)
    {
        guard let tag = sender.view?.tag else { return }
        createPopupView(button: buttons[tag])
    }
}
```

It is essential to set cancelsTouchesInView to false, else we wouldn't receive any further events !

On a longtouch on a button a popupview is created with one or more buttons above the button touched. We can swipe to these buttons directly from the button touched.

Implementation of LetterButton class:

```
class LetterButton : UIButton
{
  var delegate : LetterButtonDelegate?
  var isInside = false
```

This is called from Keyboard class:

```
  func setIsInside(val: Bool)
  {
    if (val)
    {
        if (!isInside)
        {
            setBackgroundColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!isInside)
        {
            setBackgroundColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
       }
    }
    isInside = val
}
```

Actually I only need the button here for the Keyboard class

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    if let touch = touches.first
    {
        let point = touch.location(in: self)
        delegate?.onBegan(button: self, point: point)
    }

    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

As long as we move the touch outside of the button, the movement information will be sent to the Keyboard class:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    if let touch = touches.first
    {
        let point = touch.location(in: self)
        if !bounds.contains(point)
        {
            delegate?.onMoved(point: convert(point, to: superview))
            return
        }
    }

    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
}
```

This is where the letter of the button is actually processed

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    if let touch = touches.first
    {
        let point = touch.location(in: self)
        delegate?.onEnded(point: convert(point, to: superview))
    }

    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
}
```

As we see, the LetterButton class establishes the following protocol which need to be implemented by the Keyboard class:

```
protocol LetterButtonDelegate
{
    func onBegan(button: LetterButton, point: CGPoint)
    func onMoved(point: CGPoint)
    func onEnded(point: CGPoint)
}
```

The implementation of the protocol within Keyboard class is as follows:

The button which got initially touched is stored here

```
func onBegan(button: LetterButton, point: CGPoint)
{
    buttonPressed = button
}
```

Processes background color change for buttons we swipe over

```
func onMoved(point: CGPoint)
{
    let _ = findPopupButton(point: point)
}
```

Processing of the touch ending

```
func onEnded(point: CGPoint)
{
    // Check if touch ended on a popup button
    if let button = findPopupButton(point: point)
    {
        // yes, let the keyboard process the key
        delegate?.KeyPressed(key: button.title(for: .normal)!)
        button.setIsInside(val: false)

        // remove popupbuttons
        popupView?.removeFromSuperview()
        popupView = nil
    }
    else
    {
        // remove popup buttons if touch ended anywhere else
        if popupView != nil
        {
            popupView!.removeFromSuperview()
            popupView = nil

        }

        // buttons is an array of all normal keyboard buttons
        // we use it to check if the button, where the touch ended is the same where the touch began
        for button in buttons
        {
            if (button.frame.contains(point))
            {
                if (button.button.tag == buttonPressed?.tag)
                {
                    // Still on same button, process the key
                    delegate?.KeyPressed(key: button.button.title(for: .normal)!)              break
                }
            }
        }


    }
}


// Let's see if we are moving within the bounds of a popup button
func findPopupButton (point: CGPoint) -> LetterButton?
{
    var result : LetterButton? = nil

    if (popupView != nil)
    {
        if (popupView!.frame.contains(point))
        {
            for sub in popupView!.subviews
            {
                if (sub.isKind(of: LetterButton.self))
                {
                    let button = sub as! LetterButton
                    let frame = popupView!.convert(button.frame, to: self)

                    if (frame.contains(point))
                    {
                        button.setIsInside(val: true)
                        result = button
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        button.setIsInside(val: false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}
```