# iOS: Handling long press and drag to select another button. (Like the keyboard)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, keyboard, touch

I'm having a hard time finding the right documentation for how to handle touch events in order to support similar behavior to the keyboard.

What I want is a button that when I long press it, it shows a custom view controller above the button, but I want the user to be able to drag their finger to one of the other buttons (without taking their finger off the screen).

I have the button with a long press and it's custom view controller all setup and working. What I can't figure is how to support dragging from the first button over to the other button in the view controller to be able to select it.

I've tried using a subclassed UIButton where I tried this:

`[self addTarget:self action:@selector(onDragOver:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];`

But that doesn't work.

I also found this question [How to track button selection after long press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740411/how-to-track-button-selection-after-long-press) which is precisely the functionality I'm trying to duplicate. But there are no answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution. The trick is you have to use hitTest:.

First you add a gesture recognizer to the button that is a normal button - the button that you want to open a context menu / custom view controller.

Then in your gesture recognizer callback, you use hitTest: to figure out if the user is over a custom button of yours and update it's state manually.

```
- (id) init {
    //add a long press gesture recognizer
    UILongPressureGestureRecognizer * gesture = [[UILongPressureGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onLongTap:)];
    [self.myButton addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (void) onLongTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *) gesture {

    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        //display your view controller / context menu over the button
    }

    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        //gesture stopped, use hitTest to find if their finger was over a context button

        CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
        CGPoint superviewLocation = [self.view.superview convertPoint:location fromView:self.view];
        UIView * view = [self.view.superview hitTest:superviewLocation withEvent:nil];

        if([view isKindOfClass:[MMContextMenuButton class]]) {
            //their finger was over my custom button, tell the button to send actions
            MMContextMenuButton * button = (MMContextMenuButton *) view;
            [self hideAndSendControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            if(self.draggedContextMenuButton == button) {
                self.draggedContextMenuButton = nil;
            }
        }

        if(self.draggedContextMenuButton) {
            [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }

        self.draggedContextMenuButton = nil;
    }

    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        //gesture changed, use hitTest to see if their finger
        //is over a button. Manually have to tell the button
        //that it should update it's state.

        CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
        CGPoint superviewLocation = [self.view.superview convertPoint:location fromView:self.view];
        UIView * view = [self.view.superview hitTest:superviewLocation withEvent:nil];

        if([view isKindOfClass[MMContextMenuButton class]]) {
            MMContextMenuButton * button = (MMContextMenuButton *) view;
            if(self.draggedContextMenuButton != button) {
                [self.draggedContextMenuButton dragOut];
            }
            self.draggedContextMenuButton = button;
            [button dragOver];
        }
    }
}


//////////////


#import "MMContextMenuButton.h"
#import "MMContextMenus.h"

@implementation MMContextMenuButton

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    self.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = FALSE;
    self.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = FALSE;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.435  green:0.745  blue:0.867 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(onHighlight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(onRelease:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside&UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
    return self;
}

- (void) onHighlight:(id) sender {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.435  green:0.745  blue:0.867 alpha:1];
}

- (void) onRelease:(id) sender {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

- (void) hideAndSendControlEvents:(UIControlEvents) events {
    [self dragOut];
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:events];
    [[MMContextMenus instance] hideContextMenus];
}

- (void) dragOver {
    self.highlighted = TRUE;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.435  green:0.745  blue:0.867 alpha:1];
}

- (void) dragOut {
    self.highlighted = FALSE;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

@end
```